# How to use an sql with a cursor inside to create an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How to use an sql with a cursor inside to create an SSIS package? As per the requirement we can't use a stored procedure call inside ssis. My sqlquery is to select data from multiple table using union and update certain fields according to the fetched data using cursor 'for' loop.

Comment: Use a `Execute SQL Task`. The *better* question, however, is *why* do you want to use a `CURSOR`? They are almost always used incorrectly. If you need a looping structure, SSIS will be better at that, not the DBMS.

Comment: You can't use a proc but you can use a cursor? There isn't enough info to help here, and there is definitely not enough background to understand what you are even doing

Comment: What have you tried and what errors are you getting? You have to show that you've put forth some effort. StackOverflow is not a homework completion service.

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid a cursor in SSIS using SSIS tools:

1. Execute your cursor query in execute SQL and save result into a variable of type object.
2. Add a foreach and enumerate on ADO object. Set enumeration on the variable from #1.
3. Set a variable (probably string) to each loop.
4. Use that variable as you would in your original cursor. (probably done with a function to create the SQL and an execute SQL task.